# Typescript error when accessing children component despite using React.FC

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, next.js

I have a child component which looks something like this:

```
interface ChildProps extends AnotherInterface{
    route: string,
    exitAction: ActionCreatorWithoutPayload,
}

const ChildComponent:FC<ChildProps> = ({title, shape, route, exitAction, children}) => {
    ... other stuff
}
```

The container component for this looks something like this:

```
export default connect(null, {
    exitAction,
})(ChildComponent);
```

But when I try to render the component like so:

```
<ContainerComponent
    title={action.title}
    shape={action.shape}
    route={qaction.route}
> 
<div>Some Data</div>
</ContainerComponent>
```

So this gives me the following error:

```
Type '{ children: ReactNode; title: string; shape: TActionShape; route: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Pick<Props, "title" | "shape" | "route">'.

Property 'children' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Pick<Props, "title" | "shape" | "route">'
```

Of course, I am importing everything properly, there is also no Spelling or Syntax errors what I've shown above is a simplified version of what I'm trying to do so that we can pin-point the root cause.

Please note the only error is due to the Children property, the rest of the properties that you see in the error are coming from AnotherInterface.

The web-app is using React, Redux, NextJs, ReduxToolKit & Typescript

Answer (score 0):

If a children component is being passed then the parent component must have `children: React.ReactNode` or `children?: React.ReactNode` type depending upon whether it is required or optional.

Eg:

```
<ContainerComponent
    title={action.title}
    shape={action.shape}
    route={action.route}
> 
<div>Some Data</div>
</ContainerComponent>
```

Here, `<div>Some Data</div>` will pass (not throw error) if you have `children: React.ReactNode` in the ContainerComponent type.

Further the ContainerComponent `return` should have `{children}` or use React.Children. You can read more about React.Children [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildren).

Comment: Please check the typo `{qaction.route}`

<ContainerComponent
    title={action.title}
    shape={action.shape}
    route={qaction.route}
>

Comment: That typo is just on this example that I put up, it's not present it in the actual code.

My concern is I don't think I should have to re-define `children?:React.ReactNode` as that should already come from `React.FC` from this line: `const ChildComponent:FC<ChildProps>`

Do I need to redefine that despite having `React.FC` ?